# Does replacing a fragment has any effect on it being retained during configuration change?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have multiple UI Fragments in an Activity,which are displayed only one at a time and are replaced by each other and need to be retained. I have a fragment which has an AsyncTask and is only used to retain the AsyncTask. When a fragment has been replaced, is it retained if the setRetainInstance() is set to be true? Should i manually setRetainInstance() to false when the fragment is being replaced

Comment: Where are you specifying seRetainInstance(true) ? Do you really need to retain your UI fragments (as I think you know already, this is generally not a good idea) ? That async calling fragment will be retained, but you can do as you suggest if you wish to change this behaviour.

Comment: I use fragments that host ListViews/GridViews. They display data which has to be fetched from the internet. So basically I want to retain that data. I thought retaining the active fragment would be a good idea. Could you suggest something more effective and efficient?